# Error while decrypting a filestream (CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0)

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, unity-game-engine

I've been hitting my head on the wall for the past 2 hours, without being able to see what is wrong here.

To give you context: I create an object, then I serialize it. All fine, except that when I open the file with notepad, I can see the data inside; and my class has sensitive data in it, which may be modified, resulting in a player cheating.

So I did look for an example using CryptoStream and DESCryptoServiceProvider. I can encode the file, but when I de-serialize it, I get

```
CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0.
```

This is the code that I am using; I did include only the load and save with encryption, since the functions works if I do not use encryption.

```
public class SaveManager : MonoBehaviour {

    Dictionary<string, object> savedata;
    private string path = Application.persistentDataPath;
    byte[] key = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }; // test
    byte[] iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }; //test
    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    void Awake () {
        savedata = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public void SaveGame(string savegame_name)
    {
        FileStream savefile = new FileStream(path + "/" + savegame_name + ".dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryFormatter savegame_formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        savedata = GenerateSaveDataFile(); // this create the save file
        var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(savefile, des.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        savegame_formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, savedata);
        savefile.Close();
    }

    public void LoadGame(string savegame_name)
    {  
        BinaryFormatter loadgame_formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (File.Exists(path + "/" + savegame_name + ".dat"))
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> load_file = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            FileStream loadfile = new FileStream(path + "/" + savegame_name + ".dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(loadfile, des.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            load_file = (Dictionary<string, object>)loadgame_formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
            // restore data from file
            loadfile.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("CANNOT FIND FILE");
        }

    }
}
```

I do not really know neither how to check if the file was correctly encrypted, nor if the problem is on the decryption; if I just remove the cryptostream and just serialize, everything works fine both for save and load.

Comment: As usual DES is no longer considered secure and should not be used for new work, use AES, it is no harder to use. Wondering how you came to choose DES?

Comment: Using DES with a key such as { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 } is a poor idea because DES ignores the LSB which was initially used for parity. So the key becomes, essentially: { 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8 } which reduced the key from 56-bits to essentially 48-bits. Using ASCII character has the same problem. Use a key dedication function really is necessary.

Comment: I did pick DES because it was in the example that I found online; I will try with AES. Also the key is purely for test purposes; it is my first attempt at encrypt so I did choose something really simple. Once I get this working, the plan is to move to obfuscate the function that create and store the key

Comment: DES should not be used for new work, it has been superseded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard), it is also a symmetric block based encryption algorithm.

Comment: I understand that, but the example use that...being my first attempt, I learn as I go. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307010. Beside all, why do I get that error; this is the main point of my post

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to decrypt your unencrypted (old) save file, which, when decrypted, is garbage for the padding check.

```
FileStream savefile = new FileStream(path + "/" + savegame_name + ".dat"...
```

and

```
FileStream loadfile = new FileStream(path + "/" + savegame_name + ".dbt"...
```

Notice the difference in the file extension?

As a side note, you cannot stop players from cheating. Embedding encryption keys in your code is *security by obscurity*. It might prevent casual players from cheating, but anyone with a bit of knowledge could easily extract the keys by using a decompiler.

Comment: Since "you cannot stop players from cheating" the best one can do is increase the work factor and that is worthwhile doing. One needs to decide who the attackers are they want to defend against and find a solution that increases the work factor beyond the attacker abilities. Security by obscurity may be sufficient.

Comment: @zaph A work factor is not going to help if the key used for encryption is known.

Comment: And how is the key known? Learning the key is part of the work factor. Also the anyone generally does not know how to easily extract the keys by using a decompiler. Not my mother or wife and she knows cryptography better than most.

Comment: @zaph It either has to be embedded in the code or a file the game has access to. And if the game has access to the key, the host that runs the game has access as well.
I was saying that any tech savvy person can get the key easily.

Comment: Breaking into a host is not something that is easy and host security is an entirely different thing which hopefully includes two factor authentication. As far as obtaining access to a key on the device see my previous comment. I am talking about increasing the work factor, essentially that is all security is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply' the file extension is a typo, sorry about that. BTW I am aware that I can't stop players to cheat; but it is enough for me to stop the casual player from doing so. IF someone wants to cheat to beat a game easily, is something that at least should involve a bit of work; not just open a save file and change parameters in it :) I came to terms that no matter what, a protection can be broken, so better spend time doing something that is worth, and accept that someone will mess up with your application.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did separate the save function from the encryption, and the load function from decryption, and modified a bit the code, so in fact the serialized file is closed first, and then encrypted; while decrypting the file first, before de-serialize it.

Now it works fine; took a bit but it is done. I have no clue why I was getting that error, when deserializing, would help to understand why that was happening, but at least I have a working function now for saving and loading, and still keeping the save file safe from occasional cheater.